# Dynamic IP Address Restrictions for .NET Core Web API Application on azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service, akamai

I have developed a Web API application using .net core 1.0 "version": "1.0.5" and deploying on Azure web app.

Currently, I'm facing a problem with an API endpoint when the user hits the endpoint concurrently. So for my CPU/DTU percentage increase above 60 to 100.  For that, I should restrict that user when he hit's an API endpoint concurrently. I don't have any idea to restrict those IP. I'm very new to this issue.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Note:-
When he hit's the API endpoint concurrently I should block those IP for the limited duration.

Thanks,

Parthiban.

Comment: I would recommend doing some research around rate limiting and .net core.  There are some nuget packages that can help you with this, but you will have to see if they suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You could do to prevent such issue is to use the solution provided by IIS 7.0 knows as **Dynamic IP Restrictions (DIPR) module**.

> Dynamic IP Restrictions (DIPR) key features:
>
> Blocking of IP addresses based on number of concurrent requests
>
> Blocking of IP address based on number of requests over a period of time

To get this service in Azure Website you need to configure some change on `web.config` file of your site.

1.Code snippet to to handle concurrent requests

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <dynamicIpSecurity>
            <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10"/>
        </dynamicIpSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Set the enabled property of `denyByConcurrentRequests` (under `dynamicIpSecurity` node) to true. **When a client exceeds the concurrent requests their IP will be blocked**  temporary for further request for a short period of time.

2.Code snippet to to handle maxRequests within a specified time frame:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <dynamicIpSecurity>
         <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="15" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="5000"/>
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Set the enabled property of `denyByRequestRate`. The property `maxRequests` determines the number of requests a given client IP address may send to your site and `requestIntervalInMilliseconds` determines the time frame.

IIS will automatically **start blocking requests from IP addresses when client exceeds your specified rule**. So according the value that I set client making more than 15 requests within a 5 second period will be blocked temporarily.

You could refer to how to [configure Dynamic IP Address Restrictions in Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) if you have any doubt.